# Attempting to reference a deleted function, vector.erase with vector of custom class

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to implement a Gui in SDL. Adding the following function to my gameWindow object gives me an error.

```
class gameWindow {
private:
    ...
    std::vector<guiObject> guiObjects;
    ...
public:
    ...
    void deleteGuiObjectbyIndex(unsigned int index)
    {
        guiObjects.erase(guiObjects.begin()+index);
    };
    ...
};
```

The guiObject in the function is given below:

```
class guiObject {
private:
    SDL_Rect position;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    gameWindow &gWindow;
    gameState &gState;
    eventHandler &eHandler;
    bool deleteOnClick;
    int id;

public:
    guiObject(int id,bool deleteOnClick, SDL_Rect _position, SDL_Texture* _texture, gameWindow & _gWindow, gameState & _gState, eventHandler & _eHandler) :
    id(id),deleteOnClick(deleteOnClick),gWindow(_gWindow), gState(_gState), position(_position), texture(_texture),eHandler(_eHandler)
    {};
    SDL_Texture* getTexture();
    SDL_Rect* getPosition();
    void (guiObject::*onClick)();
    void startPlay();
    bool delOnClick(){return deleteOnClick;};
    int getID(){return id;};
};
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error   C2280   'guiObject &guiObject::operator =(const guiObject &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Comment: You have references in your `guiObject` class.  As references can not be re-assigned the compiler deletes the assignment operator.  Changing them to pointers should fix the compilation error.

Comment: Ok I will give that a try @RichardCritten

Comment: It worked, thanks @RichardCritten it breaks because vector erase needs to reassign the values to change the order?

Comment: Yes `std::vector` has to hold its elements contiguously, so when you erase one it need to shuffle the elements after the erase position up to fill the hole (created by the erase), this is done by assignment. Have a read of: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase